# How many $\rm d$ orbitals do I have in $\rm [Ar]3d^{10}4s^1$ configuration materials?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, orbitals

I have noticed in a book the following band configuration for copper:

[image]

But I think I read in the book that each band has 2 electrons if it is fully occupied. But in here I see only four 3d types of energy bands which only 8 electrons can occupy. Is there a degeneracy I don't know about or am I missing something?

Comment: Which book? Aren't you given any context?

Comment: Optical Properties of Solids -Mark Fox - 2nd Edition. page 191, he doesn't relate to the issue I'm asking.

Comment: I see 5 "d" energy levels in the graph (look to the right, at letter K).

Comment: @DanielC There are 5 lines but one of them belongs to the 4S band is it not? I figured the brackets ends where they end because of the minimum energy of one of the bands all the way to the left.